How can I optimize loading large datasets in a DataGridView in C# (.NET Framework)?
I'm developing a Windows Forms application in C# that loads a large dataset into a DataGridView. When I load more than 10,000 records, the UI becomes very slow and unresponsive. How can I improve performance and make the DataGridView more responsive?
I've tried using a DataTable as the data source, but performance is still poor. Are there more efficient approaches for handling large datasets in .NET Framework?
// Use VirtualMode to improve DataGridView performance with large datasets.
public void SetupDataGridView()
{
    dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
    dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded;
    dataGridView1.RowCount = numberOfRecords; // Set the expected number of records
}

// This event retrieves data only when necessary.
private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = RetrieveDataFromDatabase(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
}

// Simulated data retrieval method; you can replace this with actual database access.
private object RetrieveDataFromDatabase(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    // Fetch the necessary data for the specific cell.
    return yourDatabase[rowIndex, columnIndex]; 
}

Explanation:

VirtualMode: By enabling virtual mode (VirtualMode = true), the DataGridView only loads data required to display the visible portion of the grid, greatly improving performance for large datasets.

Handling CellValueNeeded: Using the CellValueNeeded event allows you to fetch only the data needed for visible cells, reducing memory usage and enhancing responsiveness.


This approach is particularly useful for improving performance in Windows Forms applications with large datasets.

Why dont you use pagination? this should be the simplest approach

There have been a lot of questions about slow DataGridView. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=slow+datagridview. I suggest you look for the answer there. I would vote to close this question as a duplicate, but I don't know which of the potential duplicates has the answer to your question.

Have you done any profiling? Are you sure it is the DatagridView and not something else that is slow? Have you debugged your application to confirm that the virtualization is actually working as intended?

I've used DataGridView a lot and even if I had more than 10,000 records to display I never  needed to wait more than 8-9 seconds. I've never used VirtualMode or CellValueNeeded event, but I will definitely try them!
Anyway, everytime I simply use datagridview1.DataSource = DataTable and, if there is anything I've learned, is that when you have a lot of data you really shouldn't use dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill or dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, but (if you need it) manually set the column width: dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 150;.
Also, you should consider setting DoubleBuffered to true, in order to scroll through the data smoothly:
    Type dataGridView1Type = dataGridView1.GetType();
    PropertyInfo PropInfo = dataGridView1Type.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    PropInfo.SetValue(dataGridView1, true, null);

When I learned this it was really useful for me, I hope it can be for you too!

I think it is better to use DataGridView.DataSource to populate your DataGridView.
You didn't say what kind of items you want to show in your DataGridView. To make it easier to talk about it, let's assume that you want to show Products fetched from an Ordering database.
class Product
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public int StockCount {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}

Suppose you want to show the Id, the Name, the Stock count and the Price of all Products. For this you need a method that fetches the Products that you want to display from the database:
IEnumerable<Product> FetchProductsToDisplay(...) {...}

This procedure fetches the sequence of Products that must be displayed in the proper order. For instance, all Products that have a low StockCount, or all expensive products, whatever.
Usiing Visual Studio Desinger you have added the DataGridView and the Columns that you want to show. In the constructor you define which column shows which property of the Product:
MyForm() : Form()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    // define which column will show which property
    columnProductId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Id);
    columnProductName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
    columnProductStockCount.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.StockCount);
    columnProductPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Price);
}

You could also use visual studio designer to do this, but then the property names are assigned as strings. If in a future version you decide to change the identifiers of the properties, and forget the change the constructor, using the nameof method makes sure that the compiler will complain. You don't have to wait for the error at run time.
Displaying the Products is done in a one-liner property, so is getting the displayed Products:
BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

Showing all the Products that must be displayed is also a simple method:
void DisplayProducts()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> productsToDisplay = this.FetchProductsToDisplay(...);
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(productsToDisplay.ToList());
}

Or if you want to do this in one line:
this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(this.FetchProductsToDisplay(...).ToList());

And bingo, all your products are displayed. If you want, the operator can add / remove / change products, or change the order in which the Products are displayed. Once finished he can press the Apply Now button to process the changes:
void OnButtonApplyNow_Pressed(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<Product> displayedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts;

    // compare with original products (which you have saved somewhere)
    // to find out which Products are added / removed / changed and process the changes:
    this.ProcessChanges(displayedProducts, this.originalProducts);
}

Using the DataSource will have sped up the process considerably. If it is still too slow, consider to show the Products per page.
IEnumerable<Product> FetchProductPage(int pageNr, int pageSize) {...}

Change method FetchProductsToDisplay. so that it takes pageNr and pageSize as parameters. Inside the method it will use Skip(pageNr*PageSize).Take(pageSize) or adapt your SQL such that it only fetches the few Products that should be displayed.
In your form remember the displayed PageNr and PageSize and the total number of pages. Do this before you show the first page:
int PageCount {get; set;}                     // number of product pages
int CurrentPageNr {get; set;}
int PageSize => this.dataGridView1.RowCount;  // maybe one more or one less

The operator has two buttons, one to show the contents of the next page and one for the previous page.
void ShowPreviousPage()
{
    this.CurrentPageNr--;
    this.UpdateButtons();
    this.ShowCurrentPage();
}

void ShowPreviousPage()
{
    this.CurrentPageNr++;
    this.UpdateButtons();
    this.ShowCurrentPage();
}

void UpdateButtons()
{
    // enable / disable buttons:
    this.buttonShowPreviousPage.Enabled = this.PageNr > 0;
    this.buttonShowNextPage.Enabled = this.PageNr < this.PageCount;
}

void ShowCurrentPage
{
    IEnumerable<Product> productsToDisplay = this.FetchProductPage(
        this.CurrentPageNr, this.PageSize);
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(productsToDisplay.ToList());
}

Now that you will be showing about 24 rows, you'll never have to wait long. If it is still too slow, then the problem is withint your database management system.
